# VSCode extension: completion of token starting with colon

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a language extension and need to handle completion of tokens that start with a colon. What happens is that the original colon is not replaced and it ends up with two of them.

For example, to complete the symbol :foo, I type

```
:f
```

and it shows :foo in the list of options. I hit enter or tab to do the completion and it ends up with

```
::foo
```

How do I have it replace the original colon instead of appending after it?

Comment: Is `:` your completion trigger?  You should show more of your completionProvider code.  But you may be able to solve it with this: `myCompletion.range = new vscode.Range(position.line, position.character-1, position.line, position.character);`

Comment: I tried adding it as a trigger and that didn't change anything. I'll try setting the range and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The root problem was the wordPattern from the language config. I copied it from somewhere and it excluded colons.